# Enthought Canopy - "IOError: [Errno 10038]" when install or update packages in Package Manager

Tags: enthought

I have installed Canopy 1.7.4.3348 (64 bit). My OS is Windows 10 (64 bit). I have the most updated Canopy and Windows 10.

When I tried to update and install any packages in Package Manager, the "Status" would turn out to be "Error", and I got the message:

```
IOError: [Errno 10038] An operation was attempted on something that is not a socket.
```

I looked up the Error code on microsoft.com (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740668(v=vs.85).aspx) and found Microsoft's definition of socket error 10038:

```
WSAENOTSOCK 10038
Socket operation on nonsocket.
An operation was attempted on something that is not a socket. 
Either the socket handle parameter did not reference a valid socket, 
or for select, a member of an fd_set was not valid.
```

I think this error from Canopy may only exist in Windows but not in other OS like Linux. Could anyone please kindly help with this issue? Really appreciate it!!

The detailed messages are as below:

```
Warming up...

Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\canopy_dashboard\packman\package_action_worker.py", line 54, in run
 File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\canopy_dashboard\packman\package_action.py", line 193, in execute
 File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\canopy_dashboard\packman\packman.py", line 346, in <lambda>
 File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\canopy_dashboard\packman\packman.py", line 893, in _install
 File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\canopy_platform\cpython_packages_manager.py", line 98, in install_package
 File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\canopy_platform\enpkg_api.py", line 102, in install_package
 File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\canopy_platform\enpkg_api.py", line 177, in _execute_in_subprocess
 File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\canopy_platform\enpkg_api.py", line 212, in _propagate_progress_events
IOError: [Errno 10038] An operation was attempted on something that is not a socket
```

Answer (score 1):

Please file a bug report from the Canopy help menu for Enthought tech support records (and please refer to this SO question in your report).

I don't know what causes this rare error, but it should disappear in Canopy 2.0, which uses a different package manager backend, based on the [Enthought Deployment Manager (EDM)](https://www.enthought.com/products/edm/).

Meanwhile, you can avoid the error by using the command-line package installer, `enpkg`, from a Canopy Command Prompt. Please see this Knowledge Base article for details: https://support.enthought.com/entries/22415022-Using-enpkg-to-update-Canopy-EPD-packages.